# Lookup Table (CombiTimeTable) in OpenModelica

Tags: lookup-tables, openmodelica

I have some trouble using CombiTimeTable.

I want to fill the table using a txt file that contains two columns, the first is the time and the second is the related value (a current sample). Furthermore, I add #1 in the first line as the manual says.

Moreover, I add the following parameters:

tableOnFile=true, 
fileName="C:/Users/gg/Desktop/CurrentDrivingCycle.txt"

I also have to add the parameter *tableName* but I don't know how to define it. I tried to define it using the name of the file (i.e. CurrentDrivingCycle) but I got this error message at the end of the simulation:

*Table matrix "CurrentDrivingCycle" not found on file "C:/Users/ggalli/Desktop/CurrentDrivingCycle.txt".
simulation terminated by an assertion at initialization
Simulation process failed. Exited with code -1.*

Do you know how can I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation:
https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable.html

The name `tab1(6,2)` in the example of the documentation is the `tableName`. So yours should look something like:

```
#1
double CurrentDrivingCycle(6,2)   # comment line
  0   0
  1   0
  1   1
  2   4
  3   9
  4  16
```